# Passing char pointer array as parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

How can I pass a `char*` array as a parameter, without creating one and initializing it?

This code works (creating an initializing one):

```
char *messages[] = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"};
printf("%s", messages[1]);
```

But it wont work if you pass it like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printElement1(char *messages[]) {
    printf("%s", messages[1]);
}

int main(void) {

    printElement1({"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"});

    return 1;
}
```

I cannot use a `va_list`, the function takes a `char*` array and that's that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just missing the type for your compound literal.  Change that line to:

```
printElement1((char *[]){"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"});
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: Wow! That's incredible, I had no idea you could type cast like this.

Comment: It's not a typecast, it's a compound literal.